# Figure out code obfuscation?

Tags: c#, .net, hex, decimal, obfuscation

I'm using [Eazfuscator.NET](http://www.gapotchenko.com/eazfuscator.net) to obfuscate my code..

Now i want to make sure my strings are really impossible to understand by humans.

here is what it shows for me strings:

```
private static string \u0002 = \u0006.\u0002(107107532);
private static string \u0003 = \u0006.\u0002(107107553);
```

Can someone understand what this means?

Maybe it's Hexdecimal values or something?

Comment: Contact the vendor for support.  Oh, wait...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`\u000#` is an encoded unicode character. `\u0002\` is a static class and `\u0002` after that is one of it's methods.

There's no surefire way to fully obfuscate your code. Anyone determined enough to access it will spend as much time needed to decompile it.

Comment: Hey Minecraft Fan! xD i know it's an encoded unicode character but still you sure it's possible to figure out this string ?

Comment: To determine what it was originally called? No it is not. They would have to guess as to what everything does. Decompiling doesn't undo string/method renaming; and hello there!

Comment: I dont care if they know what the vairables name... i'm afried they finds out the value.. is it possible to find out the value ?

Comment: If you don't want a user to determine the value of the string, why are you including it at all?

Comment: @Iridium Cuz i need to use it? O_O

Comment: That's sort of my point - if you are able to use the actual value of the variable in your code, then it will always be possible for someone determined enough to obtain it regardless of how much you attempt to obfuscate it.

Comment: @Iridium I still didn't get you... offcourse i'm able to use it.. but like is it possbile for someone to figure out the original value of my  string ?

Comment: If you are able to use the value of the string somewhere in the code, then no matter how much you encrypt or obfuscate it, at the point that it gets used, it must be unencrypted. It is then a relatively easy process for someone to take the unencrypted value directly from memory at this point with the help of a debugger.

Comment: @Iridium let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2439/discussion-between-danpe-and-iridium)